# Passing Model objects into function from viewset

Tags: django, email, serialization

I have a Django viewset, where I have a function, that sends an email, whenever the viewset, is used.

I override the create function, to send the email, where I have a function, that sends the email to the user.

I want to pass in some arguments, to the function, to display in the email (done with Django's template engine)

```
class ContactRequestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = ContactRequest.objects.all()
permission_classes = [
    permissions.AllowAny
]
serializer_class = ContactRequestSerializer

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(ContactRequestViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
    send_email()
    return response

#function to send email
def send_email():
htmly = get_template('email.html')
d = {'company_name': 'dodo'} #i want this dictionary, to contain the attributes from the viewset
send_mail(
    subject='Test email',
    message='',
    from_email='test@email.com',
    recipient_list=['test@email.com'],
    html_message= htmly.render(d)
)
```

right now I just have a sample placeholder as `d` but here I want to pass in attributes from the serializers/model, that the user provided, I tried passing in the serializer, and accessing its attributes, but I don't know how to do this the proper way

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "the attributes of the viewset? Which attributes do you want to pass to the `send_email` method?

Comment: the attributes, that belong to the `Model`, so if the model had an attribute `name='Kris'` i would want that attribute for example

Comment: So you mean that you would like to have access to the newly created instance right?

Comment: Yes exactly what i mean! I'm not sure, if it's the property of the `Serializer` `Model`, or the actual `Viewset`, I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access  `response.data` after this line

```py
response = super(ContactRequestViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

which will hold the serializer's data. Yet if you want an actual instance of your model this will not be sufficient and you will need to hack your way around a little bit. The `CreateModelMixin` that is used in `ModelViewSet` of django-rest-framework has the following methods:

```py
class CreateModelMixin:
    # ... more stuff here

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

so you could override the `perform_create` method to save the instance into an attribute of your `ContactRequestViewSet` like this:

```py
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    self.instance = serializer.save()
```

then in the `create` method you could do something like this:

```py
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(ContactRequestViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)  # This calls perform_create internally
    send_email(self.instance)
    return response
```

Comment: do you know, if there is a way, to access data, from a realted table in the database, using the `Foreign key`?

Comment: Of course there is take a look at [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey). You can simply access the instance attribute corresponding to the FK